# Average Aggregation with String Timestamp

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have records in database as follow :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d4f43d69b643ac0cb9149"),
    "timestamp" : "2017-03-01 17:09:00",
    "Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Meteo_Précipitations_Precipitation status[]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Meteo_Direction du vent_Wind direction[]" : 0.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592d3a6cd69b643ac0cae395"),
    "timestamp" : "2017-01-30 09:31:00",
    "Technique-Electrique_Prises de Courant_Power1[W]" : 14.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Eclairage_Power2[W]" : 360.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_Electroménager_Power3[W]" : 0.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Aldes_Power4[W]" : 14.0,
    "Technique-Electrique_VMC Unelvent_Power5[W]" : 8.0
```

My timestamp is a simple string which I would prefer not touch because of the amount of changes on other algorithms. 
However, I would like to do some average operations. In fact, other fields are sensors names with their measurement. I have one record each minute and I would like to average these values during one hour, one day or one month.

Just before, I created one query to count the number of existing value per month for one field

```
countExistingPerMonth = client[page1.currentDB][page2.currentColl].find({"$and":[{"timestamp":{"$regex": regexExpression}}, {chosenSensor:{"$exists": True}}]}, temp_doc).count()
```

I used a $regex expression to find documents matching the chosen month.

Is there any way to do my average operations using this kind of method?

I tried to do something (below). I also tried to use regex expression to aggregate but it was not possible.

```
self.sensorsStats = []
        for chosenSensor in self.chosenSensors:   
            countPerMonth = []
            years = []
            incre_year = int(page5.combo_startYear.get())
            if (incre_year<=int(page5.combo_endYear.get())):
                while(incre_year!=(int(page5.combo_endYear.get())+1)):
                    years.append(str(incre_year))
                    incre_year += 1

            for year in years:
                for month in ["01","02","03","04","05","06","07","08","09","10","11","12"]:
                    regexExpression = '^'+year+'-'+month+'-..'

                    test = client[page1.currentDB][page2.currentColl].aggregate([{"$match":{"timestamp":{"$regex": regexExpression}}}, {"$group":{"_id":chosenSensor, "average":{"$avg":{chosenSensor}}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realistically you "should" fix the timestamp strings here. But they are at least in "lexical order" due to the "yyyy-dd-mm" format inherent in ISO Strings.

So since they have a fixed length, we can actually aggregate on them using the aggregation framework for a server side aggregation.

Sampling the month of May for date selection:

```
cursor = client[page1.currentDB][page2.currentColl].aggregate([
  { "$match": {
     "Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]":
       { "$exists": True },
     "timestamp": {
       "$gte": "2017-05-01 00:00:00", "$lt": "2017-06-01 00:00:00"
     }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "$substr": [ "$timestamp", 0, 10 ]
    },
    "average":
      { "$avg": "$Technique-Meteo_Direction moyenne du vent_Mean value wind direction[]" }
  }}
])
```

This would get the total "per day" for each day in the selected month. This relies on the lexical value of the fields. The same basic principle applies to all intervals here. So you simply fill the strings with the zero values up until the interval you want the the selection.

The same goes for the "grouping key" here, where the value to `_id` should similarly be the substring up until the required interval. Fortunately the string format is "zero padded" so values less than `"10"` are preceded by a zero as in `"05"`. Again this maintains the lexical order for "ranges".

That is what you should be aiming for, and I presume you should be selecting your fields in here, as well as generating the timestamp strings for the range selection.

But you certainly can gain something by being able to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) on the [`$substr][2]` part of the actual value to indicate your required interval, and not need to iterate multiple query invocations simply for each interval and just let the database do it for you.

Your "keys" however are another issue, and since they are not consistent you seem stuck with iterating through  the possible "key names" and performing a separate aggregation for all of them. You could possibly make the statement longer and get the "counts" and "sums" for each using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) to determine when to increment. Then you would [`$divide`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) "after" the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage to get the final "average".

That last bit is a bit complicated without knowing the full scope, and it's not all completely in your question. So I'll leave that up to you to work out, or ask a separate question about.

> **N.B** The [`$substr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) here is actually deprecated as of MongoDB 3.4. The replacement operators are [`$substrBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/) and [`$substrCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/). The operator used here is now considered an alias for [`$substrBytes`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substrBytes/), and they differ in Code Page treatment for the consideration of "length" as is documented. You should use appropriate to your Code Page, but chances are the `"timestamp"` is consistently in a single byte encoding anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The substring idea is clearly what I wanted to do. Because I didn't think about it, I tried a similar idea with $regex to have every values of "2017-03" for example. But it seems that $group doesn't like $regex or I didn't do it correctly, I don't know. However I finally decided to normalized my timestamp (from string to Date format) after I saw that it wouldn't be that complicated as I thought. I keep an eye on your last tip, I think I didn't understand it totally but I will probaly encounter a related issue soon.

Comment: @Clément Using BSON Date is the better option, and I only left it out of the answer because you explicitly stated you did not want to convert. But yes it is easy as the strings should parse quite simply. The same basic concepts on the range selection and the group `_id` basically apply though. As noted, the "key names" seem the larger problem to me and would probably be better handled by moving them to "values" within elements of an array. It does however depend on if you write to more than one in a single request. But that's another exercise and maybe another question.