# Average Aggregation doesn't take values

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have data stored like this one.

```
{'_id': ObjectId('593ab6131ccb9b0c0fb2b2a6'), 'timestamp': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 12, 8, 59), 'VOL_GAZ_CHA_I_001': '1.6466e+05', 'VOL_ECS_PUI_I_001': 4581, 'VOL_ECS_APP_I_001': 21, 'VOL_CHA_PAC_I_001': '7.9696e+05', 'TEM_SE_N_I_001': 18, 'TEM_SDB_S_I_001': 19.1, 'TEM_SAM_SO_I_001': 19, 'TEM_SAL_NO_I_001': 18.7, 'TEM_PAL_N_I_001': 18, 'TEM_GA_E_I_001': 4.6, 'TEM_FAC_NOR_I_001': 5.14, 'TEM_ENT_NE_I_001': 18.6, 'TEM_ECS_PUI_I_001': 23.1, 'TEM_ECS_APP_I_001': 37.5, 'TEM_CUI_S_I_001': 18.7, 'TEM_CHA_PAC_I_001': 23.7, 'TEM_CH3_NO_I_001': 18.1, 'TEM_CH2_SO_I_001': 19, 'TEM_CH1_SE_I_001': 18.9, 'TEM_CEL_SE_I_001': 18.3, 'TEM_BUR_NE_I_001': 18.3, 'INT_ELE_GEN_I_001': 0, 'HUM_SE_N_I_001': 56, 'HUM_SDB_S_I_001': 39, 'HUM_SAM_SO_I_001': 50, 'HUM_SAL_NO_I_001': 42, 'HUM_PAL_N_I_001': 42, 'HUM_GA_E_I_001': 88, 'HUM_ENT_NE_I_001': 42, 'HUM_CUI_S_I_001': 43, 'HUM_CH3_NO_I_001': 43, 'HUM_CH2_SO_I_001': 40, 'HUM_CH1_SE_I_001': 41, 'HUM_CEL_SE_I_001': 51, 'HUM_BUR_NE_I_001': 42, 'FLX_SOL_SUD_I_001': 35, 'ENE_ELE_USA_I_001': 0, 'ENE_ELE_PV_I_001': 1589, 'ENE_ELE_GEN_I_001': 0, 'ENE_ELE_CHA_I_001': 0, 'ENE_ELE_BTD_I_001': 0, 'ENE_ECS_PUI_I_001': '1.5729e+05', 'ENE_ECS_APP_I_001': 0, 'ENE_CHA_RDC_I_001': 0, 'ENE_CHA_PAC_I_001': 2054, 'ENE_CHA_GEN_I_001': '2.2468e+06', 'CO2_SE_N_I_001': 552, 'CO2_SDB_S_I_001': 390, 'CO2_SAM_SO_I_001': 531, 'CO2_SAL_NO_I_001': 403, 'CO2_PAL_N_I_001': 390, 'CO2_GA_E_I_001': 668, 'CO2_ENT_NE_I_001': 390, 'CO2_CUI_S_I_001': 400, 'CO2_CH3_NO_I_001': 390, 'CO2_CH2_SO_I_001': 390, 'CO2_CH1_SE_I_001': 390, 'CO2_CEL_SE_I_001': 504, 'CO2_BUR_NE_I_001': 481}
```

Each piece of data got an "_id", a date Object "timestamp" and several sensors with their own measured value. For each sensors I would like to have an average per month of their values.

The first thing I do is to select one sensor. Then I filter my dataset to get only the "_id", the "timestamp" and the selected sensor. (see $match)

Then I do an aggregation on each month of my dataset and I would like to evaluate the average of the recorded values within this month for the selected sensor.

```
for chosenSensor in self.chosenSensors:       

        monthlyAverage = client[page1.currentDB][page2.currentColl].aggregate([{"$match":{chosenSensor:{"$exists": True}}}, {"$group":{"_id":{"year":{"$year":"$timestamp"}, "month":{"$month":"$timestamp"}}, "avg":{"$avg": chosenSensor}}}])
```

However, what I got is that :

```
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 4}, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 3}, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 2}, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': {'year': 2016, 'month': 12}, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': {'year': 2017, 'month': 1}, 'avg': 0.0}
{'_id': {'year': 2016, 'month': 11}, 'avg': 0.0}
```

The average operation gives 0.0 everytime which is impossible according to values of this sensor.

An other thing is : to select the sensor I use a loop which is probably not really clean because I need to do one average query for each sensor. Is this as bad as i think? And is there any option to do this otherwhise?

Neil Lunn told me about this in a previous question and suggested some solution : [at the end of the question and in the second comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694452/average-aggregation-with-string-timestamp). But honestly I didn't understand what he suggested.

Comment: Looks like you missed the `$` in the variable argument to `$avg`. You are using the save field name variable in your code without prefixing it to the string that MongoDB expects. So `chosenSensor` needs have a string assigned like `"$sensorName"`. The `$` is important.

Comment: It was also ME. Not Will. I think you are confused with another answer. The syntax was clearly put into the answer there so you could understand.

Comment: @Neil Lunn Of course ... I just concatenated my string chosenSensor with a "$" before and it works. Thanks

Comment: @Neil Lunn yep it was you. And yes the syntax was written but It didn't come to my mind it could be that. I didn't pay attention.